# OOP - How to call a class method internally in Reason

Tags: oop, methods, ocaml, reason

I have a `testFactory` class. The purpose is to be able to pass in a factory, and then console out results for demoing purposes. As of now, when trying to call `createProductA` within the test method , the compiler will complain that createProductA is unbound (`Unbound value createProductA`).

What is the proper syntax for calling a method internally in a class?

```
class testFactory (factory: abstractFactory) => {
  as _;
  pub createProductA => factory#createProductA;
  pub createProductB => factory#createProductB;

  pub test () => {
    Js.log createProductA;
    Js.log createProductB;
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't know if I've mentioned this before, but you might want to have a look at [Real World OCaml's section on classes](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/classes.html). You can use [reason-tools](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-tools) to translate the OCaml code to Reason.

Comment: I did read that chapter, and I am constantly re-reading it(on the subway especially) and did try using _ as well as #. Probably while rushing for time, I overlooked something. My thanks as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the `as _;` part of the class definition comes in, if you've ever wondered what that was for.

`createProductA` and `createProductB` are methods, not functions, so they need to be called on an object. Reason/OCaml won't automatically bind the current object to a name like `this` or `self`, but puts it on you to do it, which is precisely what `as` does, and `_` means, as usual, "I don't care about this". So if you change `as _;` to e.g. `as self;` you'll be able to reference `self` as the current object elsewhere.

Try this:

```
class testFactory (factory: abstractFactory) => {
  as self;
  pub createProductA => factory#createProductA;
  pub createProductB => factory#createProductB;

  pub test () => {
    Js.log self#createProductA;
    Js.log self#createProductB;
  }
};
```